# Creating profile cross-sections in ArcGIS Desktop 10.x?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, software-recommendations, 3d, terrain, cross-section

Because the default 'Profile Graph' tool was not sufficient, I wrote a custom VBA script that creates scaled and exaggerated profile cross-sections in ArcGIS but I need more features:

- Visualize more than 1 surface
- Visualize vertical and directional boreholes
- Ability to symbolize / edit the output
- Linked with underlying data - changes in terrain (or profile 3D line) reflected in output

A few years ago I tested an extension by A-Prime software called 'CrossView For ArcGIS' but I am not sure if it is compatible with ArcGIS 10.0.  I contacted [A-Prime](http://www.aprimesoftware.com/) but they have not yet responded.

Are there any alternatives like 3rd party software, or a functioning script that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

[ET Tools Surface](https://www.ian-ko.com/ETSurface.html)
I use Ianko ET surface, not too expensive for the paid for version, there are some tools which are free, and arc10 is supported. The above link is from earlier. you might read through it is your programming is adept enough it might help.

I can say I am very happy with the ET geo suite which includes all of his tools!
just google ianko et tools, lot's of free stuff too

Answer (score 0):

[CrossView](https://crossviewgis.com/) DOES work at ArcGIS 10.

Just download the install bundle and select the correct installation file version.

Also, check out [Arc Hydro Groundwater Subsurface Analyst](https://www.aquaveo.com/software/ahgw-subsurface-analyst).

Answer (score 0):

Xacto section developed by Jennifer Carrell is another tool which works quite well for 2D and 3D profiles.

http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0312/files/terrainbelow.pdf