# Creating cross-sections in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polyline-creation, cross-section

Is there the possibility if I have a polyline (named "Linedivide") which is divided into,  let's say, 5 parts to make ArcGIS draw perpendicular lines of special length at the middle of all 5 parts of the Linedivide?

Can someone tell me where I can find a tool for this in the toolboxes?

Comment: First of all, welcome to GIS.se.  In general, this site functions best, and generates the best answers, when a single, focused question is asked at a time.  In addition, since you freely admit that this is for a school project, people may withhold answers on the opinion that you should be attempting to work these exercises out for yourself.  Where you may see better success is to start working on problem one, start testing a process, and then post a question about a specific problem you are encountering with your method.  Then, do the same with problem 2, but as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This questions might give you some insights:
[Creating profile cross-sections in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/how-can-i-create-profile-cross-sections-in-arcgis-10)

Depending on your data (geologic, Hydrologic, etc) and your ArcGIS version (9.3 or 10), there are a few free tools that will allow you to do this and some commercial ones with free trials.